# Thinkpad power adapters

Tags: power-supply, thinkpad

Would it be okay to plug a 90W Thinkpad power brick to a X200? It originally came with a 65W adapter but it has stopped working. So I also have a 90W adapter that came with a T61 - can I use it without any problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the voltage rating on the power supply and on the laptop. If it is the same, and socket on the notebook matches the plug on power supply, it is okay: while it *can* provide more power than needed (90W in this case), it will behavior just as the 65W one when plugged in to that laptop.

Comment: The socket is the same - I have used the 65W adapter with T61 but not the 90W one with X200. Looks like it's ok to use - information on X200 says 20V 3,25A/4,5A and the 90W adapter outputs 20V 4,5A. I plugged it to X200 and nothing exploded :) Cool