# Is it ok to use a 19V, 4.74A 90W power supply for a 19V, 3.42A laptop?

Tags: laptop, power-supply

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Thinkpad power adapters](https://superuser.com/questions/215868/thinkpad-power-adapters)
>   [Can a 20V 4.51A power supply be used with a computer that requires a 19V 3.42A power supply?](https://superuser.com/questions/245715/can-a-20v-4-51a-power-supply-be-used-with-a-computer-that-requires-a-19v-3-42a-p)

I have lost my charger for a laptop that takes 3.42A at 19V. I have a (2 years newer) charger for the same brand of laptop that provides 4.74A at 19V. Is it ok to use this charger for this laptop?

Comment: also http://superuser.com/q/245715/52492 and http://superuser.com/q/458745/52492